# Android Navigation + LiveData stopped observing when fragment goes to background

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I have 2 fragments that i navigate throught navigation component from Jetpack. When i go back from fragment 2 to fragment 1, i fire an event throught livedata from fragment 2 and fragment1 should be observing. Althought, fragment 1 didnt observed and when i sste a breakpoint to check how many observers liveData has, it say 0.
Code below

```
class Fragment1 :
Fragment() {

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
   
      myViewModel.selectedItem.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            println("Observed")
        })
 findNavController().navigate(
                    Fragment1Directions.actionToFragment2()
                )
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    myViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
}

private lateinit var myViewModel: MyViewModel
```

}

class Fragment2 :
Fragment() {

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


    myButton.setOnClickListener{
        MyViewModel().selectItem(true)
        findNavController().navigateUp()
    }
}
```

}

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

```
private val mutableSelectedItem = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val selectedItem: LiveData<Boolean> get() = mutableSelectedItem

fun selectItem(value: Boolean) {
    mutableSelectedItem.value = value
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange to not have observer for

```
myViewModel.selectedItem.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            println("Observed")
        })
```

when it's called `onViewCreated` and with `viewLifecycleOwner`, but it looks like you have a mistake for creating common `ViewModel` for `Fragment1` and `Fragment2`

Both should use

`myViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel::class.java)` to get same `ViewModel` for both fragments

Comment: Your answer was correct. Maybe i have to review livedata again